# I have an email blast going to multiple mail list segments. The link in each email for a particular segment will have a unique URL.

Tags: email, tagging

I have an email blast going to multiple mail list segments. The link in each email for a particular segment will have a unique URL.

Example:

Segment 1: http://www.example.com/link1

Segment 2: http://www.example.com/link2

Segment 3: http://www.example.com/link3

Management wants all of the segment links to land on the same page:

http://www.example.com/emaillandingpage

So, www.example.com/link1, www.example.com/link2 and www.example.com/link3 will all redirect to www.example.com/emaillandingpage

Question is, how can I track how many visits go to www.example.com/emaillandingpage from:

Segment 1: http://www.example.com/link1

Segment 2: http://www.example.com/link2

Segment 3: http://www.example.com/link3

So, I use Google Tag Manager instead?

Regards,

John

Comment: a) AWStats or whatever your server stats package is -- the URL requests section.  b) use a professional bulk mail service that includes link tracking, they do it for you.

Comment: I'm using google Analytics, but all the unique URLs (/link1, /link2, /link3) are to point to one landing page (/emaillandingpage) can I tell in Google Analytics how many visits from the email blast went to (/link1, /link2, /link3) if I have a 301 redirect on each of those pages pointing to (/emaillandingpage)?